# After I deserialize a byte stream to a string using PROTOC -- DECODE_RAW, how can I serialize a string to a byte stream

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a byte stream file "08 A5 8D 06" and I can use PROTOC -- DECODE_RAW to deserialize it to a string "1:100005". After I modify the string to" 1:10006 ", how can I serialize it to a byte stream?